# URLError<urlopen error [WinError 10054] in Tensorflow when run “mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(”MNIST_data/“, one_hot=True)”

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, mnist

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data


mnist=input_data.read_data_sets("/MNIST_data/",one_hot=True)
```

When I run this code,I got the following error:

```
URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10054] >
```

How can I fix it?Please help.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your path to mnist data. `"/MNIST_data/"` is an absolute Linux path. I believe you're running Windows, so use Windows path, e.g. `"C:\Users\username\mnist"`.

Answer (score 0):

According to latest [guide](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/contrib/learn/README.md) of TensorFlow, it is recommended to use scikit-learn to download MNIST dataset.

The following code will work easier for you:

```
mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original', data_home='./')
train_data, eval_data, train_labels, eval_labels = train_test_split(mnist.data.astype(float), mnist.target.astype(int), test_size=10000)
```